# EF Core 3.1 DeleteBehavior.SetNull with Optional Relationship fires Constraint Exception

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core, ef-fluent-api, cascading-deletes

I'm using EF Core 3.1 DB First, trying to set DeleteBehavior.SetNull for an optional relationship, but I'm still getting an exception on SaveChanges.

The entities are: `Patient` which has a nullable realtionship to `Address` in a field called `Address`.
The entities were generated by scaffold-DbContext cmd like this (I removed properties irrelevant for the question):

```
 public partial class Address
    {
        public Address()
        {
            Patient = new HashSet<Patient>();
        }

        public int Id { get; set; }
        ...

        public virtual ICollection<Patient> Patient { get; set; }
    }
```

And Patient class:

```
public partial class Patient
    {
        public int Code { get; set; }          
        public int? Address { get; set; }
        ...

        public virtual Address AddressNavigation { get; set; }
    }
```

In `OnModelCreating` function I have the following piece of code:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<Patient>(entity =>
        {
            ...

        entity.HasOne(d => d.AddressNavigation)
            .WithMany(p => p.Patient)
            .HasForeignKey(d => d.Address)
            .HasConstraintName("FK__Patient__Address__2F10007B")
            .OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.SetNull);
    });
```

When I try to remove an Address, with the following lines of code:

```
using (ClinicContext ctx = new ClinicContext())
{
    var address = ctx.Address.Find(addressId);
    ctx.Remove(address);
    ctx.SaveChanges();
}
```

I get the following exception:

> The DELETE statement conflicted with the REFERENCE constraint
> "FK__Patient__Address__2F10007B". The conflict occurred in database
> "C:\USERS\USER\SOURCE\REPOS\CLINIC\DB\CLINIC.MDF", table
> "dbo.Patient", column 'Address'. The statement has been terminated

What am I missing here?

Comment: If you are using DB first then the `.OnDelete()` behavior isn't going to have any effect unless you migrate your database. I would suspect that the constraint `FK__Patient__Address__2F10007B` in your database is not nullable.

Comment: This is the relevant part of the script for creating the table: CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Patient] (
    [Code]         INT           IDENTITY (1, 1) NOT NULL,
    [Id]           VARCHAR (9)   NOT NULL,
    [Address]      INT           NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([Code] ASC),
    FOREIGN KEY ([Address]) REFERENCES [dbo].[Address] ([Id])
);

Comment: Yes, you need to add on delete set null to your table creation query

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/alter-table-table-constraint-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15#:~:text=SET%20NULL%20All%20the%20values%20that%20make%20up,corresponding%20row%20in%20the%20parent%20table%20is%20deleted.

Comment: IMHO it's quite confusing to have both a type and a property called `Address` in `Patient`. I would call the nullable int `AddressId` or so

Comment: I agree @JHBonarius, changed it. thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @Jerry said, since you are using DB First, Add `DeleteBehavior.SetNull` in the  generated DbContext will have no effect to your database after you do the `scaffold-DbContext` commond.

You'd better recreate your table with the below statement:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Patient] (
    [Code]    INT         IDENTITY (1, 1) NOT NULL,
    [Id]      VARCHAR (9) NOT NULL,
    [Address] INT         NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([Code] ASC),
    FOREIGN KEY ([Address]) REFERENCES [dbo].[Address] ([Id]) ON DELETE SET NULL
);
```

Comment: thank you, @mj1313, this worked for me! I didn't know there is such a definition on the table itself in SQL, and also as you and @Jerry said, I didn't know that with DB First, the fluent API written in `OnModelCreating` function has no effect on the DB side.